# How much humidity is being maintained in cabin and cockpit of B787?

Tags: boeing-787, humidity

I think in general there is less than 10% humidity is being maintained in most of the commercial aircraft but I think they have improved that in the 787. I am not sure how much that is and if the cabin and cockpit have same amount of that?

Answer (score 5):

[These](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/07/20/us-boeing-dreamliner-investigation-idUSBRE96I18020130720) [sources](http://blogs.wsj.com/middleseat/2012/02/16/787-dreamliner-improvement-is-more-incremental-than-revolution-in-flying/) say that most airliners maintain a humidity of 4-7%, while the 787 maintains 10-15%. Of course these values can vary with conditions, and other sources put them [lower](http://www.airlineratings.com/news/311/787-banishes-jetlag-believe-it) or [higher](http://www.askthepilot.com/questionanswers/cabin-air-quality/).

The cabin and cockpit will not have very different air qualities. While some cockpits may humidify the cockpit air slightly, the cockpit tends to have a [greater amount of circulation](https://books.google.com/books?id=ydjOVFSW8AoC&lpg=PA52&dq=cockpit%20humidity&pg=PA52#v=onepage), leading to drier air than the rest of the cabin.

Comment: You beat me to WSJ!!!